# Increment given date for Semi-Monthly Payment Frequency on 1st and 16th of the month

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

If I know that for `semi-monthly payment frequency`, I should always use `1st` and `16th` of each month, given first date, how do I increment it?

This is what I have so
 far:

```
...
while(cnt.getAndIncrement() <= pmtNumber ) {
   monthdate = incrementDateUsingPaymentFrequency(LocalDate.of(2018, 2, 1), PaymentFrequencyCodeEnum.SEMIMONTHLY);
   //do something with this incremented month
}
...
public static LocalDate incrementDateUsingPaymentFrequency(LocalDate monthDate, PaymentFrequency paymentFrequency){
    LocalDate incrementedDate = null;
    if(paymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.SEMIMONTHLY){
        incrementedDate = monthDate.plusDays(monthDate.getDayOfMonth() == 1 ? 16 : 0);
    }
    return incrementedDate;
}
```

The result I am expecting:

```
 02/01/2018
 02/16/2018
 03/01/2018
 03/16/2018
 04/01/2018
 04/16/2018
 ...
```

Comment: What is your question **exactly**?

Comment: how do I increment given date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we know that for `semi-monthly` only to use `1st` and `16th`.
When the date is `1st` of the month, just add `15` days.
When is something else (`16th`), `add 1 month` to date and return `1st` day of that month.

```
if(paymentFrequency == PaymentFrequency.SEMIMONTHLY){
            incrementedDate = monthDate.getDayOfMonth() == 1 ? monthDate.plusDays(15) : monthDate.plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
    }
```